# Laravel 5.2 : url() function to return "https" urls?

Tags: laravel, url, https, laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel 5.2`. Below is one example of `url()` usage in one of my view (blade) file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
..
..
</form>
```

It returns me non-https urls like:
`http://www.example.com/register`

I need it to be HTTPS. I'm already using valid HTTPS on my Website.

In my `.env` file, it is already:
`APP_URL=https://www.example.com`

In my `config/app.php`, it is already:
`'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://www.example.com'),`

So **what else do i need to configure for the `LV 5.2` to return the HTTPS urls via `url()` helper function** please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `url()` you can simply use `secure_url()`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ secure_url('/register') }}">
..
..
</form>
```